# Isomorphism of enveloping algebra homomorphisms to $k$-homomorphisms?

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, group-isomorphism, ring-homomorphism, hochschild-cohomology

Given commutative ring $k$, associative $k$-algebra $A$, and $A$-bimodule $M$, we can define the **enveloping algebra** $A^e:=A\otimes A^{op}$, where $A^{op}$ is the algebra $A$ but with multiplication reversed, i.e. $a\odot_{op}b:=ba$. Then any $A$-bimodule can be viewed as a left $A^e$-module, with operation $(a\otimes b)m:=amb$.

In the source below, we have **isomorphism** $\text{Hom}_{A^e}(A^{\otimes n},M)\cong\text{Hom}_k(A^{\otimes n-2},M),$ by sending $f\mapsto\tilde{f}$, where $\tilde{f}(x):=f(1\otimes x\otimes1).$ Given $\lambda\in k,$ $$\tilde{f}(\lambda x)=f(1\otimes\lambda x\otimes1)\neq\lambda f(1\otimes x\otimes 1)=\lambda\tilde{f}(x),$$ so in what sense is $\tilde{f}$ a $k$-homomorphism? And given $g\in\text{Hom}_k(A^{\otimes n-2},M),$ how do we define the isomorphism in reverse?

Source: *Hochschild cohomology: some methods for computations*, María Julia Redondo.

Comment: Why would $f(1\otimes \lambda x\otimes 1)$ not be equal to $\lambda f(1\otimes x\otimes 1)$? If $f$ is $A^e$-linear, it is in particular $k$-linear. What do you think the $k$-module structure is on $A^{\otimes n}$?

Comment: My understanding was that $\lambda$ acts on each component of $A^{\otimes n}$, so that $\lambda(1\otimes x\otimes1)=(\lambda\otimes\lambda x\otimes\lambda)$. But you're right, this is incorrect! The reverse isomorphism is then given by $g\mapsto\bar{g},\bar{g}(x_1\otimes...\otimes x_n)=(x_1\otimes x_n)g(x_2\otimes...\otimes x_{n-1})=x_1g(x_2\otimes...\otimes x_{n-1})x_n$. Thanks for helping me clear this up.

Comment: @Cameron I suppose you notice that as soon as you put three $\lambda$s in your formula, it stops being linear!

Comment: @PedroTamaroff yes I should've spotted off the bat that the action wouldn't make sense!